# Create a list of Identity Registered Users using AspNetCore.Identity

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to construct a list of registered users for selection as a dropdown list in an application that will assign tasks to people (eventually with email integration). I have successfully made working use of AspNetCore.Identity for creating registered users.

Here is an example of what I've tried so far:

```
public class MinutaDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public List<User> QueryUserNames()
    {
        var context = new MinutaDbContext();
        var allUsers = context.Users.ToList();
        return allUsers;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public UserAssignmentController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        RoleManager = roleManager;
    }
```

The responses I've seen regarding UserManager with AspNet.Identity solutions don't work because it has a different declaration in AspNetCore and i'm unsure how to satisfy the required arguments for the above.

Is Linq required or is it possible to extract a list from:

```
public UserManager(IUserStore<TUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<TUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TUser>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<TUser>> logger);
```

Or should I be looking elsewhere, such as the IQueryableUserStore Interface?

**Update**
My DbContext constructor already extends base with argument option.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration); // Injections
        services.AddSingleton<IGreeter, Greeter>();
        services.AddScoped<INoteData, SqlNoteData>();
        services.AddDbContext<MinutaDbContext>(options => 
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Minuta")));
        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MinutaDbContext>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to inject `UserManager` into your controller, then you can use `Users` property to get all users from the database:

```
public UserAssignmentController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

    public UserAssignmentController(UserManager<User> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

     public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var users = await _userManager.Users;
        return View(users);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the constructor of `MinutaDbContext` class

```
public MinutaDbContext(DbContextOptions<MinutaDbContext> options) : base(options)
{
}
```

Then make sure you configure your `Startup.cs` file for `ConfigureServices` method.
Then if you are using repository pattern you need to add scope for your service collection. if you can publish what you have in `Startup.cs` file. That will help.

Comment: I've added the requested startup.cs ConfigureServices method as an edit above. Scope has also been added for implementation of service collection but i'm unsure how that will affect my ability to get a list of registered users?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all contributions, I've marked the answer that helped most as the problem solution. For completeness, here was my implementation of the solution. A helper class was created, returning a string of usernames, as desired:

```
public List<string> UserList  {
            get {
                var allUsers = userManager.Users;
                return allUsers.Select(x => x.UserName).ToList();
            }
        }
```